# Function execution that return an oracle type return ora-6530 error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to create the following function that return an Oracle object type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_FIPERIODDATE
RETURN FIPERIODDATE is

PDS FIPERIODDATE;

begin
  select  to_date('1/10/'||substr(pd.value,1,4), 'DD/MM/RRRR'),  
    to_date('30/9/'||substr(pd.value,6,4), 'DD/MM/RRRR') into PDS.DATESTART, PDS.DATEEND
    from parameterdetails pd inner join PROCESSPERIOD pp on pp.FIPERIODID = pd.id;
     
return (PDS);

end ;
```

following is thew FIPERIODDATE type:

```
CREATE TYPE FIPERIODDATE AS OBJECT (
  DATESTART date,  DATEEND date
);
```

when I trying to execute `select FN_FIPERIODDATE from dual;` I take ORA-6530 error, but if execute  `select FN_FIPERIODDATE.DATESTART from dual;` then I take the following error:

`[Error] Execution (21: 8): ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06553: PLS-225: subprogram or cursor 'FN_FIPERIODDATE' reference is out of scope`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a lot of things are missing.

Type you created isn't enough:

```
SQL> create or replace type fiperioddate as object
  2    (datestart date, dateend date);
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_fiper as table of fiperioddate;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function fn_fiper
  2    return t_fiper
  3  is
  4    pds t_fiper := t_fiper();
  5  begin
  6    select fiperioddate(trunc(sysdate), e.hiredate)
  7      bulk collect into pds
  8      from emp e;
  9
 10    return pds;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Does it work?

```
SQL> select * from table(fn_fiper);

DATESTART  DATEEND
---------- ----------
09.10.2020 17.12.1980
09.10.2020 20.02.1981
09.10.2020 22.02.1981
09.10.2020 02.04.1981
09.10.2020 28.09.1981
09.10.2020 01.05.1981
09.10.2020 09.06.1981
09.10.2020 09.12.1982
09.10.2020 17.11.1981
09.10.2020 08.09.1981
09.10.2020 12.01.1983
09.10.2020 03.12.1981
09.10.2020 03.12.1981
09.10.2020 23.01.1982

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Yes, it does.